# RichFaces extendedDataTable with a single column

Tags: richfaces

Is there any way to have an extendedDataTable with just a single column?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: When using a single <rich:column>, a second column shows on the right of the table. I tried also colspan, but it didn't work.

Comment: Why not simply include a small example recreating the problem?

Comment: It is not second column, it is empty space. Try setup first column width to 100%.

Comment: Thank you @VasilLukach! Setting up not only the column width, but also the table width did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rich:extendedDataTable` supports scrolling features (both horizontal and vertical) for the table body. It means width of the table body is not necessary equal table width (by default it is not).

Based on this, you should set up column(s) width (and possible table width - depend on parent layout) manually. For that purpose you can use `width` attribute of `rich:column`.

```
<rich:column width="300px">
```